# "How to fix" this function call getMatchedCount() in MongoDB-PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

This is the coding that i use to check username availability. I think there is something wrong at the `getMatchedCount()` method/function. It is because, I keep getting an error at that line, the error is:

```
'Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getMatchedCount() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\OrgChart-master\OrgChart-master\memberForgotPassword.php:35 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\OrgChart-master\OrgChart-master\memberForgotPassword.php on line 35'
```

How to fix this? or there is any other way to check username availability from the `mongodb` database?

In advance, thank you for helping me.  :)

```
if(isset($_POST['registration']))
{
       $registration = ($_POST['registration']);

       if(!empty($registration))
       {
            //$cursor = $collection->find(array("registration" => $registration));
            //$result = $cursor->count();

            $result = $db->collection1->findOne(array("registration"=>$registration));
            if($result->getMatchedCount()==0)
            {
                echo "Username Available";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "Please Enter The Correct Username";
            }

       }
 }
```

Comment: sorry my friend, but i dont understand b)

Comment: okay, so what should i do to fix this error?

Comment: i follow the documentation, it does not work at all. Hmm :(

Comment: yea, it appears as a new error call as

```

`Notice: Object of class MongoDB\Model\BSONDocument could not be converted to int in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\OrgChart-master\OrgChart-master\memberForgotPassword.php on line 36`